# Removing all whitespace in Bootstrap panel containing select list

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This has been bothering me for ever now. I've tried removing the padding from the bottom, setting the size of the select field to be the same height as the inner height of the panel, etc.

Here's my jsfiddle so you can just see what I'm talking about: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v9ec3/1159/)

I'm just trying to have that select list span the whole height of the panel with no white space at the bottom.

I've tried playing around with JQuery as well, but no success. If I resize the select menu, everything just becomes larger and the whitespace remains. A javascript solution would be fine too.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" id="obs-list">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Observations</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body scroll-list" id="list-panel">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control patient-list noglow" id="observation" name="observation" size="7">
        <option value="1">2017-03-23 04:40:36</option>
        <option value="2">2017-03-23 04:50:32</option>
        <option value="4">2017-03-28 04:18:55</option>
        <option value="5">2017-03-28 19:01:34</option>
        <option value="11">2017-03-28 22:06:25</option>
        <option value="12">2017-03-28 22:37:32</option>
        <option value="13">2017-03-28 23:10:19</option>
        <option value="14">2017-03-29 02:17:57</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my css:

```
.patient-list {
    font-size: 20px;
    border: none;
}

.panel-body.scroll-list {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

And below is that ugly looking whitespace in my list:
[image: The issue...]

Comment: not sure if i understand your question.but is this the output you looking for ?http://jsfiddle.net/v9ec3/1160/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click -> Inspect helps alot.

You will see that the element `form-group` has `margin-bottom` on it

```
.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: I had not even considered margins of the parent. Well... won't be making that mistake again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.panel-body .form-group {
  margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

[updated link](http://jsfiddle.net/v9ec3/1161/)

**Decription**

If you change `form-group` class property it will effect in bootstrap, because `form-group` class use globally for forms.. so change its property by making it as a child div..